# C++ Why does LLONG_MIN == -LLONG_MIN

Tags: c++, signed, integer-overflow, long-long

In C++ if I do this:

```
__int64 var = LLONG_MIN;
__int64 var2 = -var;
cout << "var: "<< var << endl;
cout << "var2: "<< var2 << endl;
```

The output I get is:

```
var: -9223372036854775808
var2: -9223372036854775808
```

What is the part of the standard that covers this? I assume it's signed integer overflow. This was compiled using g++ (GCC) 4.7.2.

I have a subtract function and I'm writing an add function and I thought I could just do this:
`add( someobj &obj, long long num ) { subtract( obj, -num ); }`. I think that would work if it wasn't for LLONG_MIN.

Comment: It's indeed integer overflow, and an artefact of [two's complement.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: I think the part of the standard that governs this is inherited from the C standard

Comment: @sehe IIRC signed integer overflow is UB.

Comment: @syam That's what I recall too. However, that makes no difference: whether or not it is UB is ***also*** governed by that section of the standard. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is indeed integer overflow, and an artefact of [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

On your implementation, `LLONG_MIN` is `-9223372036854775808` which is `0x8000000000000000` in hexadecimal (I will be using this hexadecimal notation because it's easier to see what happens to the bits).

When you compute `-LLONG_MIN` on a system that uses two's complement, under the hood you first make a bitwise-not (yielding `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF == LLONG_MAX`) then add 1 which overflows the signed integer and gives back `0x8000000000000000 == LLONG_MIN`.

Note that signed integer overflow is Undefined Behaviour, so there is no guarantee that it will behave consistently on every C++ implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestions how I could implement adding signed numbers and wrap around for overflow using defined behavior? I have to add a 64-bit integer to an object. If it overflows I'd prefer it wrap around rather than undefined behavior.

Comment: Re: "then add 1 which overflows the signed integer": where does the C standard say that unary - operator is implemented using bitwise-not followed by adding 1? I see that the C standard says: "The result of the unary - operator is the negative of its (promoted) operand".

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer is correct, I don't think it explain the intuitive side of this:

```
LLONG_MIN ==  -2^63      == -9223372036854775808
LLONG_MAX ==   2^63 - 1  ==  9223372036854775807
```

I was trying to think through using LLONG_MIN as a special case for something, but then I remembered that with c++ signed integral types, the lowest value is always 1 further away from 0 than the highest value (funny, every single one of them, from byte to double, ends in `-...8` and `+...7`!).

So, I was curious then as to what would happen if you were to negate the lowest value, since there is no equivalent for it in the positive realm; and, alas, it's counted as integer overflow (`-9223372036854775808 == 9223372036854775808 > 9223372036854775807`), and thus it overflows by 1 (`9223372036854775807 + 1`), leading us back to... `-9223372036854775808`!

---

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  long long l1 = LLONG_MIN;
  long long l2 = -l1; //Equivalent to l1.
  long long l3 = l1 - 1;
  long long l4 = l3 + 1;
  cout << l1 << "\n";
  cout << l2 << "\n";
  cout << l3 << "\n";
  cout << l4 << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
 9223372036854775807
-9223372036854775808
```